# A list of questions on Boyd & Vandenberghe

Tags: discussion

<sub>Work in progress. To be updated whenever the opportunity arises.</sub>

---

I take the liberty of compiling a list of questions on Math SE pertaining to theorems, lemmas, examples and exercises from Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook). Please consider linking to this list whenever someone posts a new question related to Boyd & Vandenberghe, for it may be a duplicate.

---

**Chapter 2**

- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, page 27 — intuition and proof for how a ray is convex rather than affine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3998282/339790)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3918952/339790
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — is $A \in \mathbb S^n$ redundant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024721/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — is my solution correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024681/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 2.2 — interior and relative interior points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777919/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 2.13 — what is the "convex set of joint probabilities" in this example?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1560647/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 2.15 — on $\mbox{quart}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2847156/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, Exercise 2.15g — Convexity of a region on the probability simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/613516/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 2.10 — two questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3710821/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 2.12 — How to prove this set is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4559599/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, question 2.31(d) — stuck on simple problem regarding interior of a dual cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167413/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 2.12 — image of the unit Euclidean ball under affine mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771839/339790)
- [Separability of disjoint convex sets through hyperplane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778662/339790)
- [How to prove the following for inner product and positive semidefinite matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2781736/339790)
- [Finding dual cone for a set of copositive matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091083/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — sublevel set of quadratic is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2766163/339790)
- [A confusion related to the rank of the matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2773123/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.27 — converse supporting hyperplane theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2783134/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe — Describing simplex as a polyhedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3307094/339790)
- [Proof of supporting hyperplane theorem in Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2307732/339790)
- [Show that if a convex $C$ has a supporting hyperplane at every point of its boundary, then it's convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27285/339790)
- [How to prove the following for inner product and positive semidefinite matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2781736/339790)
- [Why does the set of positive definite matrices define a half-space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1002665/339790)
- [Definition of ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3800309/339790)
- [Set of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2904491/339790)
- [How to prove $B-A \succeq 0 \Leftrightarrow$ ellipsoid $x^TBx \leq 1$ contains $x^TAx \leq 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3775804/339790)
- [Disjoint convex sets that are not strictly separated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26456/339790)
- [Solution set of an LMI is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1430571/339790)
- [Intuition for why a convex set with empty interior lies in an affine set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4100125/339790)
- [How to prove the convexity of this set by the definition of convex set？](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3562317/339790)
- [Prove or disprove that the set of probabilities $\{p \in \Delta^n \mid \mbox{Var}(X) \leq \alpha\}$ is a convex set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2928127/339790)
- [How is a line passing through the origin a convex cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249510/339790)
- [Proving that the probabilities for which the variance of a distribution is greater than some number is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4698652/339790)
- [Theorem of alternatives for strict generalized inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4705072/339790)

**Chapter 3**

- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4649061/339790
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 3.43 — First order condition for quasiconvex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4554947/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.34 — quasiconvex example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4547263/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.4 — question on Schur complements and LMIs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2828255/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, Example 3.10 — Convexity of $X \mapsto \lambda_ {\max}(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4404378/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.33 — How to prove the Euclidean ball is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4628656/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 3.40 — on the implicit function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2900162/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 3.50 — which point am I missing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2936119/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 3.51 — how to show that the number of roots is even?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919865/339790)
- [How to show that product over sum function is log concave?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2922230/339790)
- [A function is quasilinear if its domain and all level sets are convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4009327/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 3.49 (c) — proving that a function is log-concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2965417/339790)
- [Conjugate of negative normalized entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3415805/339790)
- [Finding dual cone for a set of copositive matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091083/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe's pointwise supremum notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418843/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.11 — what's the meaning of this kind of induced norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907309/339790)
- [Why is this composition of concave and convex functions concave?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322255/339790)
- [Taking derivatives inside of $\inf$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3871791/339790)
- [Show that the product of two convex functions $f,g$ is convex, when both $f,g$ are positive and nondecreasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3854747/339790)
- [Transforming semidefinite program into generalized eigenvalue problem (GEVP)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826044/339790)
- [How is this a linear matrix inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2802826/339790)
- [Is $f$ convex if the perspective of $f$ is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784790/339790)
- [Pointwise Supremum of Quasi-convex Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3735026/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 3.19(a) — I'm a bit confused](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4047662/339790)
- [When can I apply the step $X + t Z = X \left( I + t X^{-\frac{1}{2}} Z X^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4103235/339790)
- [Show $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{x_1x_2}$ is convex for $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2_{++}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3853315/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, section 3.3.4 — Quasiconvexity of linear-fractional composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603735/339790)
- [Why is $xy$ not convex although it is the product of nonnegative increasing convex functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2856316/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, section 3.6 — Convexity with respect to generalized inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4637695/339790)
- [Is this proof that a closed convex function is the pointwise supremum of affine global underestimators correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4828771/339790)

**Chapter 4**

- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 4.6 — can one replace $=$ with $\leq$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186373/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 4.4(d)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186092/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 4.55 — how to show that solution is Pareto optimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312617/339790)
- [Why is $\inf \{ \| X \|_2 \mid X \in S^n \} = \inf\{ t \mid -t I \preceq X \preceq t I, X \in S^n\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2426333/339790)
- [Why isn't this function affine?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3258172/339790)
- [About "optimizing over some variables" in Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2353130/339790)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4393502/339790

**Chapter 5**

- [How is it a single variable optimization problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344460/339790)
- [How to show that the following two problems are equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479590/339790)
- [Solve optimization problem using KKT conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3017884/339790)
- [Strong duality by Slater's condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021836/339790)
- [Steps needed to arrive at the Lagrange dual function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323352/339790)
- [Question on mixed-strategy matrix games from Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156446/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 5.6 — formulation of norm approximation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4121416/339790)
- [Problem 5.27 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4153860/339790)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4394096/339790

**Chapter 6**

- [What is a sparsity pattern in a vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1579332/339790)
- [Huber penalty function in linear programming form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030654/339790)

**Chapter 7**

- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4575596/339790

**Chapter 8**

- [Why does any dual optimal point provide a separating hyperplane between a point and its projection on a convex set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4104855/339790)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4277092/339790
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, section 8.4.2 — Maximum volume ellipsoid in an intersection of ellipsoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632247/339790)

**Chapter 9**

- [Why must a function be closed for descent methods to work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077500/339790)
- [Width of an ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2036860/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, 9.2 — how was this derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4169208/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, page 488 — convergence analysis of Newton's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279696/339790)
- [Convergence analysis of quadratically convergent phase for Newton method in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4280182/339790)
- [Boyd & Vandenberghe, Problem 9.6 — Gradient descent step for a quadratic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3387037/339790)
- [Gradient of a sum log function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2736475/339790)

**Chapter 10**

- [Given $P \succeq 0$, if $x \neq 0$ and $x^T P x=0$, can we conclude $Px=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233231/339790)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692750/339790

**Chapter 11**

- [Do primal-dual methods need to start with strictly a feasible point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193056/339790)
- [A question about using the concavity of the logarithm in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4292366/339790)
- [Why is trace operation involved when calculating gradient and Hessian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4293340/339790)

**Appendices**

- [What is the derivative of $\log \det X$ when $X$ is symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3667029/339790)
- [Second order approximation of $\log \det X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247043/339790)
- [Why is $\nabla \log{\det{X}} = X^{-1}$? Where did the trace go?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1447692/339790)

---

**To be determined**

Some questions do not mention chapter, only page number. In these cases, assigning chapter to each question is more time-consuming.

- [How to prove the following statement in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization with the help of composition rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2859912/339790)
- [Why am I getting exactly same expression for the affine underestimator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827054/339790)
- [Question on application of randomized algorithms to solve nonconvex optimization problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022829/339790)
- [Why is this set not a polyhedron?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3107639/339790)
- [$\nabla f(x)^T(y-x) \geq 0$ if $x$ is optimal for a convex $f(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3744356/339790)
- [Boundedness of sublevel sets of convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/993357/339790)
- [How can a second-order cone problem be expressed as a conic problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266572/339790)
- [What is the condition number of an ellipsoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4354001/339790)

---

**Related**

- [What does it mean for a class of problems to have a "complete theory"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4018890/339790)
- [1-week study plan to read chapters 1-5 of Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4020009/339790)

---

There should plenty more questions. If you find some, please feel free to add them to this list.

Comment: What question did you want to discuss?  The discussion tag is used when you propose a particular question or solution, and ask others if they think such a list or suggestion, or question, makes sense. I see no such question in your post.

Comment: @amWhy Where's the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790)? I do not object to migrating it to Math SE proper.

Comment: Perhaps you want to propose it as an faq, but do not use the discussion tag unless you ask others what they think of your idea.  E.g.  I could find, with certaintly 300 questions often asked out of baby Rudin.  Far more than questions out of the text you are referring to, or think of Spivak's or Dummit and Foot (Abstract Algebra).  Do you think every text from which more than 10 questions emerge on this site, should have its own meta thread?  Then to find any one post, about exercises from one specific test, will become pretty dauting.

Comment: @amWhy I never posted a question of the form "collection of questions". I figured posting it here would do the least harm. I do not particularly care about other books, especially Baby Rudin (which I dislike). If someone compiles a list of questions on Baby Rudin, I do not object to it. I do not know whether Math Meta SE can be indexed by search engines. This list could be used for internal consumption only — say, to find duplicates.

Comment: My point is, the discussion tag is inappropriate, as your dismissals of my concerns show.  You are not here to discuss whether such a list would be valuable, you simply "took the liberty" to do what you wanted to do.

Comment: @amWhy I am not dismissing your concerns. It's just that I never asked such a question, and am unaware of what the protocol is. I would not object to the creation of a question on Meta for which all answers would be collections of questions on a certain book.

Comment: "This tag [discussion] is used for questions that ask users to discuss an idea, concept, or problem in an abstract way." So, Rodrigo, are you asking users to discuss an idea, concept, or problem in an abstract way? If not, perhaps you could find a better tag for your question than the "discussion" tag.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am open to suggestions. And there's discussion involved. Just take a look at the previous comments.

Comment: So far as I can tell, Rodrigo, the previous comments are almost entirely about your use of the "discussion" tag. I doubt you were asking users to discuss your use of the discussion tag when you posted your question, and I don't think the intention of the discussion tag was to indicate questions where users would discuss the appropriateness of the discussion tag.

Comment: But if I wanted to discuss all the questions which don't use the discussion tag, should I use the discussion tag?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Should I post another question on Meta asking how these lists of questions should be handled? `At least one of these tags is required - 'bug feature-request discussion support'` — which one applies?

Comment: @amWhy I think the bigger question than whether or not the "discussion" tag belongs in this question, is which tag should we use for compiling question as Rodrigo did here because you cant ask without putting at least one tag. If I am right most of the compiled tags were done under the name Community so I don't think there's any tag over there

Comment: Regarding the tagging, it seems that the purpose is in the same neighbourhood as [List of Generalisations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions?rq=1) which is tagged discussion and faq-proposal

Comment: It seems that this question could also be an answer to the question mentioned in Calvin Khor's comment (above this one). With respect to the possibility of making it a Q/A on the Main site, [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-welcome-here) seems relevant, but not very recent.

Comment: These older questions on meta seem related, too:
[Creating a solutions manual within a single math.SE question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11971) and [About collections of questions at SE which are “solution manuals” to some book](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12016). (Maybe also: [“Hint book” for arbitrary books (Rudin, Hungerford, etc.)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11703) and [Could there be a list of selected educative questions from MSE to accompany a learner working through baby Rudin?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21656)0

Comment: I'll mention explicitly that the current question includes more than just solutions to problems; there are also questions about examples and other material

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it might be easier to list all the questions that *aren't* from Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I want to nip this in the bud. I do not cherish the prospect of there being similar meta threads about every popular textbook, no matter their merits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This specific concern seems that it would be solved if the question was made into a general question about all textbooks, and the main bit moved into an answer. (But it would open a slightly different door rather widely for other lists). It would also solve the "problem" that this Question is "unanswerable", and more closely follow the earlier List of Generalisations of Common Questions I linked which seems better received

Comment: @CalvinKhor Collecting/linking these with the List of Generalisations of Common Questions would feel better.

Comment: @CalvinKhor How about moving it to Math SE proper? It would be somewhat similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790) one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen not 100% opposed to that, but would be a widening of the scope of that question. Rodrigo: I think its very different from that question. Many questions in your list are not duplicates of each other. And questions that cannot be 'answered' or whose scope is too large (your scope is roughly one textbook) are very quickly closed and deleted on main

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What exactly do you expect to achieve by closing this question? I am not expecting an answer. Do you honestly believe I will allow my efforts to go to waste?

Comment: I want this idea discussed more widely before see the meta filled with similar threads. The past discussions left me with the impression that calling extra attention to a single book is not welcomed. I cannot quite put my finger on it. None of the threads I found are exact matches (see my next comment), but I cannot shake the feeling that this would lead to skirting on certain suggestions that were judged to not be good ideas.

Comment: [1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30584/11619), [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28898/11619), [3](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12972/11619), [4](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10056/11619), [5](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32519/11619), [6](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11323/11619). I know that you are not suggesting exactly like any of those threads, but... if taken too seriously this could become a de facto solution manual. I am uncomfortable with that way of using the site.

Comment: If this becomes something close to a solution manual I wlll consider voting to delete it. If I am in the minority, I cannot accomplish that, and will drop the matter. At this time I mostly want to raise these concerns.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It could be better than a solution manual, for it could include various solutions to the same problem. Note that I merely aggregated existing content. Anyone could rebuild the list in a couple of hours, if sufficiently motivated. In any case, if deleted, I will consider posting it elsewhere. Note that the book is used by people learning, say, machine learning on their own and who are not taking any course. In that regard, it is quite unlike Baby Rudin. Also, many of the questions listed above were posted by a student who already had access to the solution manual.

Comment: The fact that a solution manual already exists (and is not too hard to find) makes the water even murkier.

Comment: What I meant: In some past cases (probably one of the above links) the author was against the creation of the 'solution manual'. One way to resolve could have been a statement from the author, but the manual already exists

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am considering emailing the authors of the book and delete if deletion is their desire. Users with 10K+ rep points would still have access to it, I assume.

Comment: My instincts are against solution manuals in general. For they are not always used to learn. If your goal is to have something similar but even more comprehensive, it can be used by cheaters in the same way.

Comment: One instance where an author discusses his stance: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/750821/629362). Just FYR. Your post strictly speaking is not a solution manual.

Comment: Excellent resource, @RodrigodeAzevedo, thank you for your time spent on this!

Comment: The problem is that if everybody did the same with their favorite book, then meta would be cluttered. Also, the interested users can just use Boyd & Vandenberghe as a buzzword with the search engine. In other words, threads like this are not really needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If.  I can understand creating a disincentive.  However, you have been around for over a decade. How many people actually bothered to do so?  I have been around for 5 years and remember none. Why would people perform the same searches over and over again if I can do it once and be done with it? Why waste others' time? Sisyphus is a cautionary tale, not a role model. It's been 6 months and no one has created any list, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Fine. Dropping this :-)

Comment: I think [big-list] is an appropriate tag.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, the [first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554947/) under Chapter 3 should be exercise 3.43, not 3.34. I have edited the question on main, but I will refrain from editing this meta question since you seem to have some sort of schedule

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Thank you. I "refreshed" the question.